# What is the probability that all cars return within 25 days for repair?

Tags: probability

I have this question on Poisson Distribution

> A car dealer has found that 80% of the cars sold are returned to the mechanical department to correct manufacturing defects within the first 25 days after the sale. Of 11 cars sold there is interest in calculating the odds of cars returning to repairs.
>   A) What is the probability that all cars return within 25 days for repair?
>   B) If the probability of most cars returning for repairs is greater than 0.90, the association must sue the manufacturer. Based on this information, should the manufacturer be sued?

The answer for A is  $\approx 0,0859$, but I'm getting $\approx 0,0925$

This what I have tried:

$\lambda = 0.8 \cdot 11 = 8.8$
$X\sim P(X=x) = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x}{x!}$

\begin{align*}
P(X=11) &= \frac{e^{-8.8}8.8^{11}}{11!}\\
&= \frac{1.50733\cdot 10^{-4} \cdot 2.4508\cdot 10^{10}}{3.9917\cdot 10^7}\\
&= 9.2546\cdot 10^{-1}\cdot 10^{-1}\\
&= 9.2546\cdot 10^{-2}\\
&= 0.092546 \\
&\approx 0,0925
\end{align*}

And for B I would say Yes, since $0.925 > 0.9.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was **no** indication that the distribution of the number of cars that are returned for repair within the first 25 days follows a Poisson distribution.

Assuming the return of the cars are independent, we have
$$P(\text{Return all 11 cars within 25 days}) = (.8)^{11} = 0.08589934592.$$

Comment: Oh... That makes sense. I feel dumb haha

Comment: Mistakes happen. By the way, it follows the binomial distribution, and I think part b wants you to calculate the probability of at least 6 returns, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Also, please use 
[MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).